# Foreign key relationship in nested one-to-many

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, hibernate-mapping

I have these classes, with unidirectional one-to-many relationship mappings like below:

```
@Entity
public class DatabaseDetailsVO {
    @Id
    // primary key for DatabaseDetailsVO
    private String databaseName;

    @OneToMany
    private List<TableDetailsVO>;
}

@Entity
public class TableDetailsVO {
    @Id
    // primary key of TableDetailsVO must be database name 
    // and tableName with databaseName as foriegn key from DatabaseDetailsVO
    private String tableName;

    @OneToMany
    private List<ColumnDetailsVO>;
}

public class ColumnDetailsVO {
    @Id
    // primary key of ColumnDetailsVO must be columnName with
    // databaseName and tableName as foriegn key from TableDetailsVO
    private String columnName;

    private String columnDataType;
    ...
}
```

How do I address this using Hibernate annotations? I am using Hibernate 3.3.1 version.

Comment: Your third class is annotated with `@Entity`? And why Hibernate 3.3? That's *ancient*!

Comment: Yes its also an entity.Our environment has only 3.3 jar

Answer (score -1):

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "DatabaseDetailsVO")
public Set<TableDetailsVO> getTableDetailsVOs() {
    return this.stockTableDetailsVOs;
}
```

This link should help you - [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/)

Comment: Does it work for columndetails which is inside tabledetails ?

Comment: It doesnt work for columndetails which is inside tabledetails.i get unable to find column with logical name DATABASE_NAME in table tabledetailsvo and its supertables n subtables..it works ine if i comment columndetailsvo relationship in tabledetailsvo